# php error for registering a user

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

Im getting this error in a basic register script:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/func/user.func.php on line 23
```

The part of the register.php that's giving me the error is:

```
<?php

include('init.php'); // user.func.php is included in this file
include('template/header.php');
?>

<h3>Register</h3>

<?php

    // Typical $_POST stuff here, down the line the next line is where the error happenes.  Also, $register_email below is equal to $_POST['register_email'];

            if(user_exists($register_email)) { ***THIS FUNCTION IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS.  THE ACTUAL FUNCTION IS DEFINED BELOW***
                $errors[] = 'That email has already been registered';
            }
```

The function from user.func.php that's giving me the error is:

```
function user_exists($email) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; // ***THIS LINE RIGHT HERE***
}
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this error.  It's an annoying error.  Not the first time I've gotten that one.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the answers, I've tried each one and I'm getting the exact same error.  Here's the full register.php so far:

```
<?php

include('init.php');
include('template/header.php');
?>

<h3>Register</h3>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['register_email'], $_POST['register_name'], $_POST['register_password'])) {
    $register_email = $_POST['register_email'];
    $register_name = $_POST['register_name'];
    $register_password = $_POST['register_password'];

    $errors = array();

    if(empty($register_email) || empty($register_name) || empty($register_password)) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields required';
    } else {
        echo 'OK';
        }
        if(filter_var($register_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) {
            $errors[] = 'Email address is not valid';
        }
        if(strlen($register_email) > 255 || strlen($register_name) > 35 || strlen($register_password) > 35) {
            $errors[] = 'Ayo, quit tampering with the html';
        }
        if(user_exists($register_email)) {
            $errors[] = 'That email has already been registered';
        }
}

if(!empty($errors)) {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error.'<br />';
    }
} else {

    }

?>
```

Comment: it seems like the query is not executing correctly you should check the statement you wrote

Comment: probably the mysql_query returns false, var_dump the $query variable

Comment: check the value of $email if its set or not

use this
if(isset($email)) before making the select statement

Comment: If your error reporting is not strict, then you really don't need to predefined your empty array: `$errors = array();`

Comment: And also I would make the empty field checkups individual. Lets say one field is empty and email is in incorrect format. Then with individual empty field checkup, the user could pass the form 100% with the next submit. But in your case he/she will first have to submit to find out that his fields are set and then second submit to get rid of the incorrect email format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I must say first that I'm not a mysql specialist and I normally use a DB class (so should you.) But if you are saying that `return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;` line is giving you an error. It means that the line above is not working. Meaning that it is not returning a resource.

You should first debug your function..

```
function user_exists ($email) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    if (!mysql_select_db("users")) {
        echo 'Could not select "users" DB.<br />Error: ' . mysql_error();
    }
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS `count` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
    echo 'The count is currently: '$query['count'];
    // return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

If it says that it couldn't select the users DB. Then the problem is in your connections. As I said, I'm no pro. But you should probably connect it like this:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysqluser', 'mypass');
```

Now you can try this:

```
function user_exists ($email) {
    global $conn;
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    if (!mysql_ping($conn)) {
        echo 'Could not ping the mysql. Connection is lost probably :(';
    }
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS `count` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'", $conn);
    echo 'The count is currently: ' . mysql_result($query, 0);
    // return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

If the code is been debugged and connection is AWESOME! Then:

```
function user_exists ($email) {
    global $conn;
    if ($email) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS `count` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'", $conn);
        if (mysql_result($query, 0)) {
            return true;
        }
    }  
    return false;
}
```

Or:

```
function user_exists ($email) {
    global $conn;
    if ($email) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS `count` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'", $conn);
        if ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            if ($result['count'] == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }  
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You gotta check each and every step along the way. Otherwise you can have the dumbest mistakes and overcomplicate things exponentially. Your zen like approach to the answer was right on. I scrapped all the code and started from the beginning with error check along the way. I must have stricter error handling and more frequent checks so I don't write 200 lines of code and line 5 is messing it up.

Comment: Cool, well still, some recommendations: 1) Some quick research on mysql classes, find what you like and start using one -- much easier to debug, less code, neater. 2) I recently had the error reporting topic up on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104818/how-important-are-php-notices-really). Definitely check it out, so you wouldn't over-code because all of those notices. Undefined array probably produced a notice right? But technically it was correct and functional. // Anyways, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
function user_exists($email) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    if (false === $query) return false;
    return (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will fix it, if the error is stating a boolean was passed to mysql_result it would indicate the query failed altogether

Comment: That didn't work.  I also tried making the return a turnery operator and the same result.  Got the same error with both of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), `mysql_query()` can return a ressource (thats what you expect) *OR* `FALSE` if an error occur.

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
function user_exists($email) {

    if(isset($email){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $result = mysql_result($query,0);
    if($result ===false) {
    //error occur with the sql statement 
     //handel the error
    }
    else
    return ($result == 1) ? true : false; // ***THIS LINE RIGHT HERE***
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function user_exists($email) {
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
  //return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; // ***THIS LINE RIGHT HERE***
  if( $query ) return ( mysql_result($query, 0) != "" ) ? true : false;
}
```